# floor of a matrix in OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a matrix of type Mat. I want to calculate floor of the Mat. I have searched the Operations on Arrays and The core functionality documentation.

Below is a sample code

```
Mat M = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 1.2, 0.3, 0.9, 2.3, 1.1, 0.7, 10.2, 10,3, 8.0, 11.6);
```

I am looking for something like

`floor(M, M)` or

```
M = floor(M)
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this? Platform C++

Comment: I don't think there is something like this. Why don't you write it yourself, simply looping through the array elements?

Comment: The M I have in my actual implementation is huge (50000x3). Anyhow, I used M.converTo(M, CV_32S).. I observed that the operation does rounding operation and I am ok with it...Any issues if I use it..??